# How to load partial into view when a link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, partial-views

I have a list of user 'submissions' in my Rails app, and when a user submission is clicked, I would like the full submission to load into the view, without having to go to a new page.

Here's the code for the list of submissions:

```
<div id="submission-list-container">
    <% current_user.submissions.each do |i| %>
        <a href='#'>
            <div id="post-container">
                <%= i.title %> 
            </div>
        </a>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

The partial I have created, `<%= render "show", :submission => i %>,`, works fine, but I would like the full submission to be loaded into the view  (index.html.erb), when that link above is clicked. Is there a good method for doing this? Should I just do something else like an AJAX call in JavaScript? I like these partials because it feels more clean and organized to seperate code.

My partial is pretty simple at the moment:

```
<%= submission.title %>
<%= dat_markdown(submission.content) %>
```

Comment: I think you're looking for an AJAX call, yes.

Comment: Darn... okay, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a TitlePane in the Dojo Toolkit, and probably there's a similar widget with jQueryUI.

I can only speak to the Dojo Toolkit's version

You would do something like:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/TitlePane" data-dojo-props="href: '/blah', title: '<%= submission.title %>', open: false">
```

You can include this in your application layout for lite usage of dojo, loaded from a CDN:

```
<script data-dojo-config="async: true, parseOnLoad: true"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.9.1/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

The TitlePane is wired up so that when it is expanded, it will autoload the content that is provided to the href parameter.

While this isn't exactly a rails solution directly, it can be used as an alternative.

For a Rails Solution, you can simply use an AJAX call to a controller that renders the partial. You may even be able to hook it up using the

```
def blah
  @submission = Submission.find(...)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # default render
    format.js # js behavior
  end
end
```

then a blah.html.erb

```
<%= render partial: 'submission/submission', object: @submission %>
```

with the partial

```
<div id='submission-<%= submission.id %>'>
  <div id='submission-<%= submission.id %>-title'><%= link_to(submission.title, 'blah/blah', remote: true) %></div>
  <div id='submission-<%= submission.id %>-content'></div>
</div>
```

and a blah.js.erb

```
$.get('/submission/content', function(data) { $('#submission-<%= @submission.id %>-content').html(data) } );
```

and an entry into the submissions_controller with route

```
def content
  @submission = Submission.find(...)
  render text: @submission.content
end
```

This probably isn't an exact solution, but hopefully it'll put you on the right path.